# Canopy Editor: control cell delimiting? Or: how to apply magic to a couple lines in a file?

Tags: python, ipython, enthought

Is there a way to "bound" magic when you're just writing code in the text editor in enthought Canopy? For example, if I want to do %timeit on, say, 3 lines of a document, and then want to run the whole file at once, is there a way to limit the "scope" of %timeit?

For example, say I have this in my text editor document:

```
print "hello world"
%%timeit 
print "I want to time this command when I run this file!"
print "this one too!"

print """but I want the timer to stop before this command runs, 
           even when I run the whole file. """
```

Any suggestions? Is there a magic command to end one cell and start another?

Thanks!

(This is useful for %%cython commands in the middle of long files.)

Answer (score 1):

You may well know this, but for the record, the standard solution is to use a profiler. I recommend [line_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/) which is available pre-built to Canopy subscribers, or you can build yourself (this is non-trivial if you are using Windows).

I am also adding the ipython tag to your question. Magic commands can't be used directly in a Python source file, but it's possible that calling into IPython itself might provide a solution; if so, someone monitoring the ipython tag might know how.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Yeah, line_profiler does work for timing -- the use case I most had in mind was compiling cython functions in docs. The ```%%cython``` magic is so nice!        Regarding the ability co call magic, canopy is odd in that if you hit "run" in the editor, it feeds it into an interactive ipython session, so magic does work. The only problem is that if I hit run on a full doc, I can't figure out how to delimit cells. But thanks!

Comment: The design (and I *think* the actual functioning) is that the Run command always runs the full file (using IPython's %run magic), whereas the Run Selection command pastes the current selection into the shell as commands to execute.